# WPF Multiple dictionaries for single control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

I have one button control for which i have associated one dictionary, In that dictionary i have change the control template of the Button control but now on different screen i don't want to applied that dictionary on Button control i want to change the template. How this thing can be achievable?

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" >

   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    Some control template changes

   </Style>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you defined a style for a button. You want this style applied to button on Screen1.

But for the button in screen2 you dont want to apply the same style.

Applying the style for all buttons, it depends on what is the scope of your resource dictionary. If its application scope the style will be applied to all buttons in all screens.

`<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>`

If you want the style to specific to screen 1, create this dictionary only in screen1 user control so that scope will remain to only for that user control like...

`<Usercontrol.Resources>
 <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />
<userControl.Resources>`